# Render success/failure page using mailchimp marketing api v3 response code in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I want to render a succes.html file if my contact is successfully added to the Mailchimp list else a failure.html file. I am using Mailchimp marketing API ver:3.

I have tried this code but can't render the files.

```js
async function run() {
        try{
            const response = await mailchimp.lists.addListMember(listId, {
                email_address: subscribingUser.email,
                status: "subscribed",
                merge_fields: {
                    FNAME: subscribingUser.firstName,
                    LNAME: subscribingUser.lastName
                }
            });
        } catch (e){
            if (e.response.statusCode  !== 200){
                console.log(e.response.statusCode);
                res.redirect(__dirname + "/failure.html");
            }else{
                console.log(e.response.statusCode);
                console.log(`Successfully added contact as an audience member. The contact's id is ${response.id}.`);
                res.redirect(__dirname + "/success.html");
            }
        }

    }
    run();
```

I have tried searching for this problem, but all the results that I found were using the older version of Mailchimp and using HTTPS req/res and not using `async function run()`. But I want to solve the problem using mailchimp's `async function run()`.

Answer (score 0):

so I've figured out that I'm doing the try-catch in the wrong way. After editing the code a little now it works fine. The working code is given below.

```js
  async function run() {
        try{
            const response = await mailchimp.lists.addListMember(listId, {
                email_address: subscribingUser.email,
                status: "subscribed",
                merge_fields: {
                    FNAME: subscribingUser.firstName,
                    LNAME: subscribingUser.lastName
                }
            });
            console.log(`Successfully added contact as an audience member. The contact's id is ${response.id}.`);
            res.sendFile(__dirname + "/success.html");
        } catch (e){
            console.log(e.status);
            res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html");
        }

    }
run();
```